# Angularjs UI grid Hide vertical scroll bar when number of rows does not overflow grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Let's say my ui grid can only show 10 rows, and if I have 20 rows I have to scroll up and down.
How do I make the vertical scroll bar only shows up when the rows are > 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(data.length > 10) {
  $scope.gridOptions.enableVerticalScrollbar = 1;
} else {
  $scope.gridOptions.enableVerticalScrollbar = 0;
}
$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
```